# How do I connect 2 PCs to one monitor?

Tags: hardware

I have 2 PCs : (2 motherboards,2HDD,2RAM,2graphic cards) but only one
mouse one monitor and one keyboard. How do I connect all these togeather
so that I can switch between the two PC to see them on my single LCD monitor?
How is called such a box? I'm a complete newbie to hardware.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used switchers for many years but when I did the generic ones from Amazon or eBay worked flawlessly for me. As with all thinks Ubuntu related make sure the devices work with Linux and your hardware before purchasing.

The [HDMI plus keyboard or mouse switcher](https://www.amazon.ca/Switcher-Keyboard-Display-Desktop-Controller/dp/B07M63D22S/ref=asc_df_B07M63D22S/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=337450414220&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12872323338591253653&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9060769&hvtargid=pla-753184940621&psc=1) looks like this:

[image: keyboard mouse switcher.png]

The [HDMI monitor only switcher](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07CKNQGHF/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07CKNQGHF&pd_rd_w=MybYY&pf_rd_p=4b7c8c1c-293f-4b1e-a49a-8787dff31bcb&pd_rd_wg=IK6WF&pf_rd_r=YV86W1K0D0R4A28ZMHFV&pd_rd_r=b7071c9f-a594-11e9-a041-afcf3c2cca71) looks like this:

[image: hdmi monitor switcher.png]

You might also be interested in [4 USB sharing](https://www.amazon.ca/UGREEN-Computers-Peripheral-Switcher-One-Button/dp/B01N6GD9JO/ref=asc_df_B01N6GD9JO/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292982081894&hvpos=1o5&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10730395564397275252&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9060769&hvtargid=pla-350939791158&psc=1) to complement option 1 and 2 above:

[image: 4 usb port switcher.png]

Comment: But I have only ONE monitor but 2 PC. Can I still use 2PCs share 4USB devices?? What is the name of this last option of you on Amazon? Thank you!

Comment: Click the link to read the full Amazon description. Yes you can use 2 PCs to share up to 4 USB devices. You already have two-one mouse and one keyboard. Later on you might add one printer or whatever and have three devices shared between two computers.

Comment: May I ask you yet, if I buy [this](https://www.tsbohemia.cz/aten-2-port-dvi-kvmp-usb2-0-mini-audio-1-2m-_d167750.html?fulltextword=hdmi%20kvm%20switch) and have only one PC, will it work well?

Comment: @user3357120 well I can't read the language in that link but the picture is worth a thousand words and it looks like it will work. I always read the user reviews before purchase to make sure satisfaction is > 75% and learn common problems and solutions. Then the day it arrives I can solve any common problems that may occur.